# Should POJOs be abstracted?

Tags: java

My coworker tends to have each POJO implement an interface. 
Like Customer would implement ICustomer, with the motivation that we can now have multiple implementations of ICustomer. One example would be a JPA annotated JpaCustomer with the motivation that now we're not tied to JPA. It seems like overkill to me to abstract it that much. What are your opinion on this? Is this common?

Comment: Welcome to programmers stack exchange. This Q&A site and questions asking for opinions are tend to be discouraged. Please take some time to read this http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ and thishttp://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and see if you can reword this question to be a bit more objective. Thanks!

Comment: You nailed it. Unfortunately, P.SE users can't do the talking to your coworker on your behalf. It would be up to you to offer the  advice in a friendly way,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The purpose of an Interface is to *allow multiple implementations.*  If you already require multiple implementations of a particular Interface, well then.

But having one Interface object per POJO on the off-chance that you might need more than one impelementation for each POJO is unnecessary, and creates a lot of extra work for no discernible benefit.

Comment: For POJOS, I totally agree. But for something more complex like a product data store, creating an interface can crystalize your thinking, leading to a nice clean separation of concerns.

Answer (score 2):

In practice it is a good idea to wait until you have at least two concrete implementations before you abstract them into an Interface or Abstract Class.  Trying to "abstract" from a single implementation is unnecessary, and, even worse, it is almost certain to be wrong or incomplete because you would miss something.

For example, imagine that your first **Mammal** you implement is a **Dog**.  Create **IMammal**.  How well will **IMammal** work for a Bat, a Whale, and a Kangaroo?